# How to store array data to struct?

Tags: arrays, swift, structure

i want to store "1" and "2" in datas1 as well  "3" and "4" in datas2.

```
struct Datas {
    let datas1: String
    let datas2: String
}

 var datas : [String] = ["1","2","3","4"]
```

Comment: It’s quite unclear what you want, could you add the expected end result to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store multiple strings in a variable, you should make it a collection like an `array`

```
struct Datas {
    let datas1: [String]
    let datas2: [String]
}
```

then you can assign them like:

```
var datas = Datas(
    datas1: ["1","2"],
    datas2: ["3","4"]
    // TODO: Don't forget to handle the rest of elements!)
```

---

#### Update due comments:

You can define a custom initializer that takes an array and build the struct:

```
extension Datas {
    init(array: [String]) {
        datas1 = Array(array.prefix(2))
        datas2 = Array(array.suffix(2))
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
let datas = Datas(array: ["1", "2", "3", "4"])
```

---

**An Opinion to the data structure itself**:

It seems like a two-dimensional array is a better fit for these datas:

```
let datas: [[String]] = [["1", "2"],["3", "4"]]
```

usage:

```
print(datas[0]) // ["1", "2"]
print(datas[1]) // ["3", "4"]
```

Comment: but i want single array only.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: i mean, i have single array only as i say in question

Comment: So you say you need the first two elements into the datas1 and the last two in to the datas2 ?